# gradle sourceSets on mutli-project

Tags: gradle, source-sets

My gradle multi-project layout is so:

```
rootProject
  |-- project1
  |
  |-- project2
  |
  |-- src
  |    |-- main
  |    |    |-- groovy
  |    |    `-- resources
  |    |-- test
  |    |    |-- groovy
  |    |    `-- resources
  |    `-- sanity
  |         |-- groovy
  |         `-- resources
  |
  |---- settings.gradle
  `---- build.gradle
```

project1 and project2 are configured in the build.gradle (in rootProject).
I want to change project1 and project2 **testClassDir** to **sanity**.

My *build.gradle* is so:

```
subprojects{
    apply plugin: "groovy"

    sourceSets {
        sanity {
           groovy.srcDir "src/sanity/groovy"
           resources.srcDir "src/sanity/resources"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        sanityCompile sourceSets.main.output
        sanityCompile sourceSets.test.output

        sanityCompile configurations.compile
        sanityCompile configurations.testCompile

        sanityRuntime configurations.runtime
        sanityRuntime configurations.testRuntime
   }
   runTest {
        testClassesDir = sourceSets.sanity.output.classesDir
        classpath = sourceSets.sanity.runtimeClasspath
    }
}

project('project1) {
}
```

I've followed this [Blog](https://www.michael-bull.com/blog/2016/06/04/separating-integration-and-unit-tests-with-gradle*), I'm trying to understand why the configuration doesn't work on multi-project.

Comment: You might be interested in [this](https://github.com/uklance/gradle-java-flavours/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/lazan/javaflavours/JavaFlavoursPlugin.groovy#L23) code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found the solution.
I needed to define the sourceSets in the root project to the new test folder.
In the subprojects I needed set the test directory to the rootProject.
The new *build.gradle*:

```
// On root project
sourceSets {
    sanity {
       groovy.srcDir "src/sanity/groovy"
       resources.srcDir "src/sanity/resources"
    }
}

dependencies {
    sanityCompile sourceSets.main.output
    sanityCompile sourceSets.test.output

    sanityCompile configurations.compile
    sanityCompile configurations.testCompile

    sanityRuntime configurations.runtime
    sanityRuntime configurations.testRuntime
}

subprojects {
   apply plugin: "groovy"    

   runTest {
        // Redirect the class dir to rootProject 
        testClassesDir = rootProject.sourceSets.sanity.output.classesDir
        classpath = rootProject.sourceSets.sanity.runtimeClasspath
    }
}

project('project1) {
}

project('project2) {
}
```

Comment: Royg, can you clarify your own solution? Is rootProject an actual Gradle variable? And second, you reset classpath to equal ....sanity.classpath. Aren’t you resetting entire project classpath?